# Tkinter: Window flash when attempting to click away

Tags: python, tkinter

Ive been trying to do this for a while now, but haven't figured out a way to do it.

I have a tkinter script, that creates a popup window when a button is pressed. However I don't want the user to be able to click away from this window to any previous windows created. I have got this working with root.grab_set(), however there is no indication to the user that they must stay on that window.

```
class popup(object):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.root=Toplevel(parent)
        self.root.grab_set() #prevents the user clicking on the parent window
                             #But the window doesnt 'flash' when an attempt to click away is made
```

For example, when you have a window created by the filedialogue module, if you attempt to click onto another window the filedialogue window stays on top and has a 'flashing' animation to let the user know they cant click away. Is there a way I can reproduce this effect? Going through the source of filedialogue hasn't been fruitful for me, and neither have Google searches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way i can think to do this is to use an event and the focus commands, along with the windows `bell` command:

```
#!python3

import tkinter as tk

class popup(object):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.root=tk.Toplevel(parent)
        self.root.title("Popup")
        self.root.bind("<FocusOut>", self.Alarm)

    def Alarm(self, event):
        self.root.focus_force()
        self.root.bell()

main = tk.Tk()
main.title("Main")
pop = popup(main)
main.mainloop()
```

Comment: Well thats one way I guess. The window doesnt flash but atleast there is some indication they need to stay on the window. However you are still able to interact with the parent window with this method, but the child window simply grabs the focus back very quickly

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution for Windows that uses [`FlashWindowEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679347(v=vs.85).aspx) from the `user32` dll. You need to pass a [`FLASHWINFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679348(v=vs.85).aspx) object to it. The `grab_set` makes sure the popup window stays in focus and disables any widgets in the main window, making the popup transient makes sure it's always on top of the master. The `<Button-1>` event is used to check mouse clicks, and `winfo_containing` checks if another window than the popup is clicked. I then set the focus back to the popup and flash the window in focus (which then always is the popup).

You need [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) to use this.

```
import Tkinter as tk
from ctypes import *
import win32con

class popup(object):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.root=tk.Toplevel(self.parent)
        self.root.title("Popup")
        self.root.grab_set()
        self.root.transient(self.parent)
        self.root.bind("<Button-1>", self.flash)

    def flash(self, event):
        if self.root.winfo_containing(event.x_root, event.y_root)!=self.root:
            self.root.focus_set()
            number_of_flashes = 5
            flash_time = 80
            info = FLASHWINFO(0,
                              windll.user32.GetForegroundWindow(),
                              win32con.FLASHW_ALL,
                              number_of_flashes,
                              flash_time)
            info.cbSize = sizeof(info) 
            windll.user32.FlashWindowEx(byref(info))

class FLASHWINFO(Structure): 
    _fields_ = [('cbSize', c_uint), 
                ('hwnd', c_uint), 
                ('dwFlags', c_uint), 
                ('uCount', c_uint), 
                ('dwTimeout', c_uint)]

main = tk.Tk()
main.title("Main")
pop = popup(main)
main.mainloop()
```

---

As it is now, the flash only occurs when the main window's body is clicked, so clicking the title bar just returns the focus to the popup without flashing. To make it fire also when that happens you could try using the `<FocusOut>` event, but you would have to make sure it only happens when the focus passes to the main window, but it never really does since the `grab_set` is used. You might want to figure that out, but as it is now it works quite well. So it's not perfect, but I hope it helps.

Comment: Ideally I'd like this using just the default python libraries, as this needs to be an easily portable system.

Comment: Also, I have seen self.root.transient(self.parent) before, however when I have been trying to use it, it has just caused the window to not show. could that be something to do with the parent window being already visible when the popup is created?

Comment: I just edited the event trigger and check a bit so it works better in my opinion. I can't think of a real solution with only default pyhton, sorry. Maybe someone else can. I'll just let this answer stay here for other people trying to do the same who might find this question and don't mind the use of pywin32. As for the `transient` problem, that might be worth asking another question.

Comment: I found that `self.root.focus_set()` didn't really do what I wanted.  But on linux at least, calling `self.root.focus_force()` (perhaps with a time delay using `self.root.after(...)` works pretty well...