# python - tkinter print from text box to screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

In tkinter, I am trying to print the text entry from text box to screen every time I click the button "click"

This is my code which is working fine

```
from tkinter import *
def get(s):
        print(s.get())
win=Tk()
s=StringVar()
button=Button(win,text='click',command=lambda:get(s)).grid(row=1)
ent=Entry(win,textvariable=s).grid()
```

But when I do the same from new window, it is not working.
This is the code that doesn't work

```
from tkinter import *
def get(s):
        print(s.get())
def newwin():
    win=Tk()
    s=StringVar()
    button=Button(win,text='click',command=lambda:get(s)).grid(row=1)
    ent=Entry(win,textvariable=s).grid()
root=Tk()
but=Button(root,text='New',command=newwin).grid()
```

Everytime I click the 'click' button, I see a Blank line...
But I want to see the output just like the previous case.
Thanks in Advance !!

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
def newwin():
    win=Tk()
...
```

to

```
def newwin():
    win=Toplevel(root)
    ...
```

Edit (clarification):

Your code would also run if you change

```
 def newwin():
    win=Tk()
    s=StringVar()
    ...
```

to

```
def newwin():
    win=Tk()
    s=StringVar(win)
    ...
```

but you shouldn't run multiple Tk() instances. See a good explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37502942/tkinter-creating-multiple-windows-use-new-tk-instance-or-toplevel-or-frame)

Edit:
As for restricting selection of old window as asked by OP in a comment, I suggested to add a line to `newwin()`:

```
def newwin():
    win=Tk(Toplevel(root))
    s=StringVar()
    button=Button(win,text='click',command=lambda:get(s)).grid(row=1)
    ent=Entry(win,textvariable=s).grid()
    win.grab_set() # win will catch all events, until you close it
                   # so user cannot interact with root window widgets
    # root.widthdraw() # alternative approach hides root window
                       # until Toplevel closes


root=Tk()
but=Button(root,text='New',command=newwin).grid()
```

Edit:
(further enhancement with code rewrite. I think I already answered the OP question but the comments with additional questions can be confusing. Please try to ask a single question at a time in order for you to select the best answer for that question)

Now I just rewrote the thing to look like a more coehrent answer. Look that using `grid` or `pack` is not relevant here. I hope you find it educational. Notice the different imports. You can import differently, but this way you do not import all the `tkinter` module names. `ttk` widgets are just modern versions of the classic ones. I subclassed `Toplevel`, assured parent `__init__` is called and kept the new window related things together in that class. Note also the use of `grab_set` and the event callback for when the child toplevel loses focus. This way root window never regains focus unless you close the child. So no window select. This is adapted from selected answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28541381/tkinter-window-flash-when-attempting-to-click-away/28543248#28543248)

Note also that I do not keep any reference to the newly created window. If you need so, you have to adapt (maybe store the result of `MyWinddow(root)` in a global var)

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Tk, ttk

class MyWindow(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent, *kw):
        super().__init__(parent, *kw)
        self.title('New Toplevel Window')
        self.myvar = tk.StringVar()
        self.button = ttk.Button(self, text='Print myvar',
            command=self.print_myvar)
        self.entry = ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.myvar)
        self.button.pack(pady=5)
        self.entry.pack(padx=50, pady=5)
        self.grab_set() # capture all the events
        self.bind('<FocusOut>', self.dont_let_focus_go) # cannot focus root


    def print_myvar(self):
        print(self.myvar.get())

    def dont_let_focus_go(self, event=None):
        self.focus_force()

def new_window():
    MyWindow(root)

root = Tk()
root.title('My Application Root Window')

button = ttk.Button(root, text='New Window', command=new_window)
button.pack(padx=50, pady=5)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: just added an explanation in the answer above.

Comment: How do I restrict selecting the old window ?
till I close the NEW WINDOW (Toplevel) I should not be able to select the old window....
How do I do this ??

Comment: Add `win.grab_set()` as the last instruction in your `newwin()` method. The new window will capture all the events.

Comment: from tkinter import *
def get(s):
        print(s.get())
def newwin():
    win=Toplevel()
    s=StringVar()
    button=Button(win,text='click',command=lambda:get(s)).grid(row=1)
    ent=Entry(win,textvariable=s).grid()
    win.grab_set()
root=Tk()
but=Button(root,text='New',command=newwin).grid()                   Is this what you mean ?? It didn't work :( @progmatico

Comment: Is this what you mean ?? It didn't work :(
from tkinter import *
def get(s):
        print(s.get())
def newwin():
    win=Toplevel()
    s=StringVar()
    button=Button(win,text='click',command=lambda:get(s)).grid(row=1)
    ent=Entry(win,textvariable=s).grid()
    win.grab_set()
root=Tk()
but=Button(root,text='New',command=newwin).grid()

Comment: See my edit in the answer. Catching all events allows for another window selection, but you cannot do anything in it (widgets won't get events).  An alternative is to hide the root with `widthdraw()`.

Comment: I exactly copy pasted your code (with library), but didn't work... :(
Is it "win=Tk(Toplevel(root))" or "win=Toplevel(root)" 
Because "win=Tk(Toplevel(root))" gave me an error and "win=Toplevel(root)" didn't work....
Am doing this in a Raspberry Pi (Debian Linux)...would that make any difference ? Because I noticed the colorchooser window is different in a Windows tkinter and mine...

Comment: Thanks, I see that grab_set works...but the difference is....The root window GETS SELECTED but if I click the NEW BUTTON AGAIN, it wont work....But the root window can get the focus, while the toplevel is active....Is there a way, that it can never be even focused when the toplevel is active ??

Comment: See my edit. Rewrote the thing. Hope it is useful and answers your question.

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped alot !!

Comment: Your reference to colorchooser window... they are different because (i think) colorchooser uses a window from the underlying system OS, not a window built with tkinter itself. Appearence will depend on the OS, that is normal.